# How to modify apalike.bst to insert a space before the page numbers?

Tags: bibtex

which part of apalike.bst do I have to change to insert a space before the page numbers?

Instead of "12(4):194-201" I need "12(4): 194-201"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a copy of `apalike.bst`, called (say) `qwerty-apalike.bst` and modify the `format.vol.num.pages` function:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
%        { ":" * pages n.dashify * }% <-- commented out
        { ":~" * pages n.dashify * }% <-- added a 'non-breaking' space
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Then use the modified `.bst`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{adams1986,
  author =   {Adams, Marilyn McCord},
  title =    {The Structure of {Ockham's} Moral Theory},
  year =     1986,
  volume =   46,
  pages =    {1--35},
  journal =  {Franciscan Studies},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{apalike}
\bibliographystyle{qwerty-apalike}
\begin{document}
\cite{adams1986}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```